Clarification on using Clang 19.1.1 and g++ 14.2.0 for C++ 20
I installed Clang 19.1.1 and G++ 14.2.0 for running C++ 20 on my Vscode, I had written the correct code and  made necessary changes to run the program I am always getting an error. Something like this 
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -std=C++20 "C:\Users\user\Desktop\C++\Learn Project\C++ From Advanced To Beginer\FreeCodeCamp.C++" -o "C:\Users\user\Desktop\C++\Learn Project\C++ From Advanced To Beginer\FreeCodeCamp.exe"
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=C++20'; did you mean '-std=c++03'?

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

Please what should I do now, I am just a beginner. Enlighten me.
#include <iostream>

Integer main(){
    auto result = (10 <=> 20) > 0;
} 

For the JSON
I tried this
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "CPPBUILD",
        "label": "Build with GCC 14.2.0",
        "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "Build with GCC 14.2.0",
        "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "-std=c++20",
            "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/FreeCodeCamp"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\clang++.exe"
    },
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "Build with clang 19.1.1",
        "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\clang-cl.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "-std=c++20",
            "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/FreeCodeCamp"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\clang-cl.exe"
    }
]
}

and I am expecting a result like
build run successfully after runing task and give output 0

In a command prompt type C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe --version and add the output to the question.

Use a beginner-friendly IDE instead of VSC, e.g. Visual Studio.

Not related to the problem, but Integer is not a type in C++ ... It's simply int

Also compiler options are case sensitive -std=C++20 should be -std=c++20 but I don't see the uppercase version in the files above.
